# How do i manage ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Below is a simple program which searches for sequential characters. However I get an exception because I'm searching outside of the array index. I understand why it occurs but unsure how do I manage this?

```
public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String term = "Popeye's fishCat";
        String query = "P's SalmonCat";
        int score = 0;

        char [] termChar = term.toCharArray();
        char [] queryChar = query.toCharArray();

        if((queryChar[0]) == (termChar[0]))
        {
            score++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < queryChar.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < termChar.length; j++)
            {
                if(queryChar[i] == termChar[j] )
                {
                    if((queryChar[i + 1]) == (termChar[j + 1])) //Causes an exception
                    {
                        System.out.println((queryChar[i + 1]) + " " + (termChar[j + 1]));
                        score++;
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }

        System.out.println(score);
    }
```

Comment: actually what are you trying to do :S

Comment: You're adding one in a loop that ends with `length`, and wondering why it's out of bounds?

Comment: are you trying to find total number or characters that are present in both of the strings?

Comment: No just sequential matches

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adjust your loop conditions:

```
for(int i = 0; i < queryChar.length - 1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < termChar.length - 1; j++)
```

Note the added `-1`

If you always look at the *next* item in the loop, you can't loop to the last item, because it doesn't have a *next* item.

Comment: Ah thank you. I was attemptig this trying to check if values was null, but with no joy. So simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove i +1 or j+1 in this bit

```
if((queryChar[i + 1]) == (termChar[j + 1])){
    System.out.println((queryChar[i + 1]) + " " + (termChar[j + 1]));
    score++;
    break;
```

}
As legnth returns the size of the array, counting the first element as 1, but when getting elements from an array, the first is labeled zero. Using length - 1 ( the highest possible value in that loop, as when i = length the loop stops), and then adding 1, tries to refer to array[length], which doesn't exist. As it starts at zero, so the last element is array[length-1]